# My NSDictionary somehow has multiple values for one key

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have been attempting to debug a issue with my code, and just came upon an odd phenomenon. Found this in the debug area when a breakpoint was triggered:

[image]

Am I correct in observing that there are multiple values for this key: `@"6898173"`??

What are possible causes of this? I do not set those key-value pairs using the string literal, but by getting a substring of a string retrieved and decoded from a `GKSession` transmission.

I still have this up in the debug area in xcode, incase theres anything else there that might help.

EDIT:

By request, here is the code that would have created one of the two strings (another was created at an earlier time):

```
[carForPeerID setObject:[[MultiScreenRacerCarView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simple-travel-car-top_view"] trackNumber:[[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes] substringWithRange:range] intValue]] forKey:[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]] substringFromIndex:9]];
```

The string in `data` might look something like this:
`car00.0146898173`

EDIT:

Code that sends the data:

```
[self.currentSession sendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"car%i%@%@", [(MultiScreenRacerCarView *)[carForPeerID objectForKey:peerID] trackNumber], speed, [(MultiScreenRacerCarView *)[carForPeerID objectForKey:peerID] owner]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] toPeers:@[(NSString *)[peersInOrder objectAtIndex:(self.myOrderNumber + 1)]] withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

Sorry its hard to read. Its only one line.

Comment: can you try to print the memory address of each key?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella
key [0]: `0x08779290`

key [1]: `0x09298de0`

Comment: so apparently even though the two strings have the same value, they are two different objects. Weird, though...

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I originally thought that there was maybe a possible space at the end or something, but that didn't appear to be the case. Thats also why I mentioned that I am not using string literals, but going through a process to get the string. Is is possible that there was a decoding issue that caused the strings to not be perfectly identical? Would my code that creates this string be helpful?

Comment: @0x7fffffff I have not tried. But I think I may have found the reason...just a moment

Comment: Every time it receives a message, it logs it. One time, it logged a extra character on the end of the string. It was a upsidedown question mark. When I attempt to paste the log here, the odd character disappears.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Does this sound like an encoding issue?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Does this sound like an encoding issue?

Comment: If you aren't using string literals for keys, then the actual objects are different even if they have the same value. @SantaClaus What happens when you try to get the object for that key?

Comment: @Abizern which key? Do you want the key's object or the value's object?

Comment: Just feel like reposting this: **Every time it receives a message, it logs it. One time, it logged a extra character on the end of the string. It was a upsidedown question mark. When I attempt to paste the log here, the odd character disappears.**

Comment: The object for that key. Alternatively in the debug console type `po carForPeerID` to see what the dictionary actually holds rather than showing us what is in the inspector window.

Comment: @Abizern I cannot tell which key is the bad one, because it does not show the odd character in the debug area, only the log. Both objects appear to be valid, but one obviously is the one I want, due to certain properties that are set. Both keys are valid as well. I don't know if I am interpreting your question correctly, but I am doing the best I can.

Comment: The point is that the debug window is often just plain wrong, when it displays mutable arrays/dictionaries.  Don't trust that display -- either use NSLog or `po`.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I understand that. I am currently trying to reproduce the issue, and this time log the output of the dictionary.

Comment: **I was unable to reproduce the issue, but I think the real cause of the issue lies somewhere in my text encoding. I encode the string with `[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and decoding it with `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]`, where data is the data received from another ios device (that encoded the data with the encoding method above).**

Comment: **Also, given that I cannot reproduce the issue, it is not really a top priority for me (and should not be for anyone else). If you have any insight, feel free to give it, but don't break your back over this . (not that anyone here would)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is a debugger "feechure".  When you have a mutable dictionary and modify it, the debugger may not show you the correct view of the object.

To reliably display the contents of an `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`, switch to the console and type `po carForPeerID`.

Comment: See, this is why I should write more answers and less comments :)

Comment: @HotLicks I do not deny that it is not showing me what I want to see. Read my bolded comment above. That is kinda the problem now. The odd character doesn't show up in the debug area, and I understand that. The reason I am not logging the full contents of the dictionary is because I am not sure if I can reproduce the situation, but I will try.

Comment: @SantaClaus - The view above appears to be of the debug variable display window.  That view cannot be trusted.  And you have not explained what "messages" you're receiving or how you're "logging" them.

Comment: @SantaClaus - And what is "it"?

Comment: @HotLicks "it" is the debug area. Yes that is from the debug variable display window. Yes, it cannot be trusted, you have allready said that and I have already acknowledged it. in the question I said I am using `GKSession` to send data ("messages") from one device to another. I am logging the string that is contained in a `GKSession` data "message".

Comment: Although this was only part of the issue, I am accepting it anyways.